# Primefaces datatable each row error message

Tags: primefaces, datatable

I am trying to show an error message for each row inside a primefaces datatable
Here is my xhtml, I removed some of the tags and some javascript functions are omitted for the sake of clarity

```
    <f:view>
    <h:form id="mainEditForm">
     <!-- <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true"               closable="true" />  -->
      <p:dataTable id="configTable"
        value="#{favoriteReportsQueries.myFavoriteReportsQueriesPreferences}"
        var="repList"
        selection="#{favoriteReportsQueries.selectedFavoriteReportsQueries}"
        rowKey="#{repList.reportFavoriteName}">
        <p:column headerText="Report / Query">
          <h:selectOneMenu id="reportQuery" value="#{repList.reportURL} onchange="submit();"    update="reportGivenName">
          <f:valueChangeListener type="cmecf.ui.favoritereports.validator.CustomNameValueChangeListener" />
            <f:selectItems
              value="#{favoriteReportsQueries.applicationReportsAndQueries}"
              var="appRepList" itemValue="#{appRepList.value}"
              itemLabel="#{appRepList.label}" />

          </h:selectOneMenu>
        </p:column>
        **<p:column headerText="Custom Name">
          <p:inputText id="reportGivenName" 
            value="#{repList.reportFavoriteName}" size="50"/>
            <f:validator validatorId="cmecf.favoritereports.CustomValidator" for="reportGivenName"/>

            <p:message for="reportGivenName"/>

        </p:column>**

        <p:column style="width:10px;">
         <f:facet name="header">
             Delete

         </f:facet>

         <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="deleteId"
           styleClass="selectBooleanCheckbox"
           value="#{repList.delete}">
           <p:ajax event="valueChange" process="@this"></p:ajax>
         </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
       </p:column>




      </p:dataTable>
      <h:panelGrid columns="7">
        <p:column>
          <p:commandButton id="savePrefs"
            action="#{favoriteReportsQueries.storeReportsPreferences}"
            oncomplete="resizeiFrame()"
            value="Save" ajax="false" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column></p:column>
        <p:column>
          <p:commandLink value="Add New"
            action="#{favoriteReportsQueries.addNewRow}"
            oncomplete="resizeiFrame()"
            update="configTable" />
        </p:column>
        <p:spacer width="2px"></p:spacer>
        <p:column>
          <p:commandLink type="reset" value="Clear"
            action="#{favoriteReportsQueries.restorePreferences}"
            oncomplete="resizeiFrame()"
            update="configTable"  ajax="false" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column></p:column>
        <p:column>
          <p:commandLink value="Cancel"
            action="#{favoriteReportsQueries.cancel}"
             ajax="false" />
        </p:column>

      </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>

  </f:view>
```

I implemented the validator which just returns an error message

```
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.validator.FacesValidator;
import javax.faces.validator.Validator;
import javax.faces.validator.ValidatorException;

@FacesValidator("cmecf.favoritereports.CustomValidator")
public class CustomNameValidator implements Validator{

    @Override
    public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component,
            Object value) throws ValidatorException {
        FacesMessage msg = 
                new FacesMessage("Name already exists", 
                        "Invalid name");
            msg.setSeverity(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR);
            throw new ValidatorException(msg);


    }



   }
```

When I run this app I am getting this error

```
<f:validator> Parent not composite component or an instance of EditableValueHolder: org.primefaces.component.column.Column@be0296
```

Thanks in advance
Sai

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
<p:inputText id="reportGivenName" 
            value="#{repList.reportFavoriteName}" size="50">
            <f:validator validatorId="cmecf.favoritereports.CustomValidator" />
</p:inputText>
```